# CSS on hover , layout changes

Tags: css, conflict

I am displaying a list of orders which logged in users have placed and the status of the orders.

Data displays perfectly like :

[image]

But when I hover mouse on previous/next buttons i.e. page navigation menu then it looks something like :
[image]

That menu behaves different or not as per expectation.

I have put whole page in zip file that I have [attached](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5iD-XmIofPYMEZMbEQyWlVpcUU/edit?usp=sharing) here on my google drive.
When I remove style1.css from it then it works fine but all page formation I have provided inside it, so anyone help me for that how to avoid css conflict.

Thank You.

Comment: Please include the relevant portions of your code here.

Comment: No this is not the right way to ask your question.  Showing your whole project code is not a wise decision.  Take some time inspect using dev tools and makes changes accordingly.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn voted mistakenly on demonstrated minimal option, wanted to vote on ssc, can you close vote this? else it will attract all imaginary answers

Comment: @Mr. Alien: Are you able to cast a different close vote if you retract your original one?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn nope, I told you to cast one so that it closes that instance..

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan  - I have not put y whole project, I have put one static page with it's css and javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because on line 180 of your style1.css file, on `:hover` of the `li` it is changing the display property of the `li` from inline to block:

```
 ul li:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Removing this style stops this from happening.

Comment: Totally awesome sir. It help me a lot. I am just confused that what to do but you have just solved it in a minutes. Thank you,